# WYSIWYG Text Processor, configure margins for print

Tags: javascript, web, editor, wysiwyg

it is possible to configure margins for printing in CKEditor. If is not, would text processor do you recommend?

I'm working in a project that its very important to print with margins and templates, one of the major features that users is asking me is to print with "asymmetric margins".

I cant find this options, it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

These settings are determined in the browser settings. I'm pretty sure they can't be set programmaticly.

Comment: if a use word or openoffice i can configure margins, footnotes, endnotes, i found a plugin for footnotes http://www.voofie.com/content/122/building-citation-footnote-plugin-for-ckeditor/ if you are interesed.
I wonder if a can configure this with a template or in the hole page like in word.